# Connect different size circle with line in css

Tags: html, css, less

How to create responsiveness UI which display in following link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykuCw.png

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use jsPlumb javascript library which is useful for doing cases such your case, library link [jsPlump](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/)

I hope my answer would be useful